# How to scale a Text widget that would behave like a scaling of an image

Tags: flutter

I would like to perform an Hero transition that will change, at the end, the size of a Widget.
This widget contains some text.

By default, the text widget will resize and the text inside move and resize to fit the text widget.

I would like to make to whole widget behave like an image would do : Everything will scale (zoom).

I tried :

auto_size_text package : The text will still move and the result is not perfect

screenshot package : It take too long to generate the image, replace the current widget with the image before performing the hero transition.

I am thinking about RenderRepaintBoundary, but this seems a lot of work for a simple task.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you want to achieve, you may want to use [FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html).

This is what I used to create the animation below, where the Text widgets have a different size between the beginning and the end of the animation:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Romain, the easy answer was indeed FittedBox.

Making a Hero transition that will change the size of a Text Widget will be smooth when I put a FittedBox on the second page.

But I needed to pass down the original size to the second page to make the Text inside the FittedBox appear on the same number of lines that it was previously displayed.

Here the result :
https://vimeo.com/346745092

Here the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const String textThatCouldChangeDependingOnContext = "Hero Text .... ";

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage()));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey _textKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(64.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Hero(
                tag: 'tag',
                child: Material(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text(textThatCouldChangeDependingOnContext,
                        key: _textKey),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Fly'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Size originalTextSize = _textKey.currentContext.size;
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              MySecondPage(originalTextSize)));
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Size originalTextSize;

  MySecondPage(this.originalTextSize);

  @override
  _MySecondPageState createState() => _MySecondPageState();
}

class _MySecondPageState extends State<MySecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Hero(
                tag: 'tag',
                transitionOnUserGestures: true,
                child: Material(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: widget.originalTextSize.height,
                        width: widget.originalTextSize.width,
                        child: Text(textThatCouldChangeDependingOnContext),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```